# I want to verify that my camel consumer app is throwing specific exception via junit test

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, junit, apache-camel

```
 // custom exception

        public class customexception () {

        log.error("exception);
        }

    --- apache camel consumer app which has custom exception

        public consumer app implements Processor {

        //process & validate

    @override
    public process(message) {

        if(condition met)
             throw customexception();

        }
       }

        // my junit test class

        @runwith(CamelSpringBootRunner)
        @springboottest
        public mytestclass {


        @Autowired
        ProducerTemplate producer;

        @Test
        public testexception () {

        producer.sendbody("invalid message");

        //??? assert customexception is thrown by consumer

        }
        }
```

Here Junit's expectedCondition will not work because I am not getting exception in test but standalone consumer app which is listening to the message produced by my test is throwing exception.

Comment: junit4? junit5? Also, what have you tried already? Show us please.

Comment: junit4. I have added code snippte which can be helpful

Answer (score 0):

> ... my test is not throwing exception but consumer app which is listening to the message produced by my test is throwing exception.

JUnit cannot intercept exceptions that are not thrown on the current stack, or that don't bubble up to the test.

It sounds like you are unit testing in the wrong place, or at the wrong level of granularity.

The behavior (throwing the exception) is not a behavior of the class you are testing.  It is a behavior of the consumer app.  So the test that the exception is thrown should be in the unit test for the consumer app.

- The unit test for this class (the producer) should be that it produces messages of the kind that would / should generate an exception.  It should probably be talking to a "mock" for the consumer app that captures the messages for checking by your test.
- The unit test for the consumer app should likewise consume messages from a "mock" producer.  This test is where you check that the appropiate exception is thrown.
- You could also test this at the integration test level, but then you might be testing that the consumer app is (for example) logging an error in its log file in the scenario that should lead to this behavior.  Or maybe you don't need to test this.